# Data integration using R

Tags: r, merge, dataset, data-integration

I am trying to integrate data by merging two data-set in R, I am wondering if i can use the function **merge()** but i want to specify the column witch have the same information in one result column here is an example:

**dataset 1 :** 
            |FirstName  | LastName | Age | Eyes-color |

**dataset 2 :** 
            |FN  | LastName | Age | Gender |

i want to merge dataset 1 and dataset 2 in one dataset (dataset 3) and specifying that "FN" is same as "FirstName" so i want it to be one column 
so the result should be :

**dataset 3 :** 
            |FirstName  | LastName | Age | Eyes-color | Gender |

Comment: Just rename FN to FirstName, `merge(by = c("FirstName", "LastName"))` and you should be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the same column name and then use it to merge the data.

```
names(dataset2)[1] = "FirstName"
dataset3 = merge(dataset1, dataset2, by="FirstName")
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to merge by the FN / FirstName as the common variable the you can do in one `dplyr` chain to `rename` and use `merge`:

```
dataset3 <- dataset2 %>% 
  rename(FirstName = FN) %>% 
  merge(dataset1, by = "FirstName")
```

Answer (score 1):

With the dplyr package you can do that with:

```
dplyr::inner_join(
x = dataset1, y = dataset2,
by = c("FirstName" = "FN")
)
```